# Best reading on "writing on dirty paper" ?

Tags: it.information-theory

Can one suggest good introduction(s) to "dirty paper coding" ? (Other comments, suggestions etc. are highly welcome).

---

Some background.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirty_paper_coding

"Writing on dirty paper" - is the name of the quite famous paper in information theory:

M. Costa (May 1983). "Writing on dirty paper". IEEE Trans. Information Theory 29 (3): 439–441. doi:10.1109/TIT.1983.1056659.

The analogy (which is not 100% correct, but inspiring) - assume that you given a sheet of paper with many dirty  places - you need to write a message to another person, such that he will be able to understand it.

The main surprise of the theorem is the following - you can do it the same successfully as if the paper would be clean.

Currently this topic is interesting for industry since "dirty paper" is interference coming from the other users of wireless networks.

Comment: For those of us casually browsing, could you say something about how this differs from the classical problem of how to communicate down a noisy channel, as considered by Shannon? 

Comment: @Tom let me follow the analogy with "dirty paper". Shannon's setup: you write something on white paper, then noise is added in some random places which are UNKNOWN to both  writer and reader; after that "reader=receiver" gets this paper and tries to decode. Costa's setup - the writer receivers "dirty paper" with dirty places KNOWN to  him writer(=transmitter), but unknown to reader(=receiver), he writes his messages and after that again the noise is added which is both unknown to reader and writer; after that reader(=receiver) tries to decode. So Shannon: received_signal= sent_signal+noise, 

Comment: @Tom (2) Costa: received_signal= sent_signal + noise + "interference", where "interference" - is known to writer(transmitter), but unknown to reader(=receiver). 

Answer (score 2):

What about

1. D. Tse, *Fundamental of Wireless Communication*, Cambridge University Press, 2005, Chap. 10, available free [here](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~dtse/book.html);
2. C.B. Peel, *On "Dirty Paper Coding"*, Signal Proc. Mag., May, 2003, avaliable [here](http://faculty.cua.edu/regalia/EE572/dirty_paper_coding.pdf);

Also, if your Institution have access I suggest [IEEE Xplore](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/search/searchresult.jsp?newsearch=true&queryText=dirty+paper&x=0&y=0)

**ADDED:**

1. J. Liu, N. Elia, [Writing on Dirty Paper with Feedback](http://www.ims.cuhk.edu.hk/~cis/2005.4/03.pdf), Comm. Inform. Systems, International Press, Vol. 5, No. 4, pp. 401-422, 2005